# SQL Update in PHP isn't working, not redirecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This should update a row with new information from a form if a certain button is pressed, then redirect a page. However, this code does neither.

```
if(isset($_POST['editBtn'])) {
    require_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['option'])) { 
        $option = "1"; 
    } else { 
        $option = "0";}
    $uid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

    $db->query("UPDATE members SET
        uid = $uid,
        option = '$_POST[option]',
        WHERE uid = $uid");
    $db->close();

    header('location: view.php?id='.$uid.'');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You should be using `$option` in the query, not `$_POST[option]`

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['editBtn']` is set?

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning.

Comment: `option = '$_POST[option]',` <<< that trailing comma; is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

```
$db->query("UPDATE members SET
    uid = $uid,
    option = '$_POST[option]',
    WHERE uid = $uid");
```

**Use Below Code :**

```
$db->query("UPDATE members SET
    uid = $uid,
    option = '".$_POST['option']."',
    WHERE uid = $uid");
```

If you want to save `$option` as value in database, then you should use below code :

```
$db->query("UPDATE members SET
    uid = $uid,
    option = '$option',
    WHERE uid = $uid");
```